# Where can I see the list of all the items I have returned on Amazon?

Tags: amazon

Where can I see the list of all the items I have returned on Amazon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon does not have a specific list of returns that were completed (ie. returned item  was received by Amazon), however there is a list of **Return Authorizations** created in the past 2 months in the [Returns Centre](https://www.amazon.com/spr/returns) <sup><sup><sub>( USA )</sub></sup> *****</sup>

**<sup>*</sup> Global URL Syntax**
Links throughout this answer are to Amazon.com, Amazon's US site however they can be modified for your country's site by changing the top level domain (TLD) extension to point to the Amazon site in your country.

Fore example,

```
Returns Centre: https://www.amazon.[tld]/spr/returns

#  USA      https://www.amazon.com/spr/returns  
#  Canada   https://www.amazon.ca/spr/returns  
#  Mexico   https://www.amazon.com.mx/spr/returns  
#  UK       https://www.amazon.co.uk/spr/returns  
#  France   https://www.amazon.fr/spr/returns  
#  Italy    https://www.amazon.it/spr/returns 
#  Spain    https://www.amazon.es/spr/returns
```

##### Links to Other Resources

1. [Help and Customer Service](https://www.amazon.com/hz/contact-us/foresight/hubgateway)

   ```
   https://www.amazon.[tld]/hz/contact-us/foresight/hubgateway
   ```
2. [Help... > Returns and Refunds](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201819090)

   ```
   https://www.amazon.[tld]/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201819090
   ```
3. [Help... > Returns... > Exchanges and Replacements](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=GVCF2744DMWT4L8S)

   ```
   https://www.amazon.[tld]/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=GVCF2744DMWT4L8S
   ```

Answer (score 3):

There is a list as of 2023, but it is not obvious and only available from desktop site.
Go to the returns and replacements link in the footer of the main page:
https://www.amazon.com/gp/css/returns/homepage.html?ref_=footer_hy_f_4
Then select the link for view your returns:
https://www.amazon.com/spr/returns/history?ref_=orc_spr_return_center_view_more_returns_ref

This will likely change so hope someone gets to enjoy it before it disappears.

Comment: curious why this got a downvote.  Did it not work?

Comment: FYI it wasn't my downvote but perhaps it was downvoted because **A.** It is discouraged to answer old questions unless you have something substantial to add.  **B.** Your answer is a duplicate of this 5 year old [**accepted** answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/121037/) **C.** It is discouraged to include meta-commentary in answers.  Hope that helps.  See [answering questions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I think this answer is much more direct. I couldn't even find list via the accepted answer!

Comment: @Bort If answers can be improved for clarity, it is encouraged to edit them.